# How can I check that my Adobe Flash installation is up to date?

Tags: update-manager, flash

[image: Screenshot of Update Manager]

I have, recently, noticed permission errors when installing updates to Adobe Flash. Are these serious? Is my Flash installation fully up to date? How can I check?

Comment: So the warning in your output is not too bad and didn't affect the update you installed. Anyway, you can check the exact version of Flash your browser is running by visiting https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/about/ - there you also see which version is the latest for each OS.

Comment: The warning messages do not block FlashPlayer update. It is known [bug 1522675](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1522675), after long discussion with developers it is fixed.  Please wait some hours or one-two days.

Comment: Hmm, @ByteCommander, it is a duplicate, but the accepted answer there says to take some actions which, by my reading, are no longer necessary, as the underlying bug has been fixed. Am I reading that wrong?

Comment: Dunno, I think changing the ownership of that directory to _apt would not hurt. I don't know whether there was a related fix or not. The issue is not critical, as stuff still works, but it might be a minor security problem if apt downloads these files as root instead of the unprivileged _apt user...

Comment: @ByteCommander. I've just checked. It's already owned by `apt:root` with permissions `drwx------` as suggested. So something somewhere must have already made those changes for me.

Comment: I think it should be `_apt` instead of `apt`. Was that a typo?

Comment: My typo, indeed, @ByteC. It is `_apt`.